# Does Not Sent Ajax Post Data On Internet Explorer 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

When I sent post data using AJAX call on IE 10,It does not work.it works when i change the document mode from page default to IE9 standards or change browser mode to IE9 .
I have already added following lines..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<META http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=9" />
```

My code looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "TopologyViews/deleteSegment",
            data: {
                segment_id: segment

            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {

            }
        });
```

Please help me.

Comment: add `error` callback and check for any error you receive

Comment: I tried adding(error: function(xhr, status, error) {}) .errors were not prompted.

Comment: you have to alert them up like `(error: function(xhr, status, error) { alert(xhr); alert(status); alert(error);}`

Comment: `https://10.128.51.181/TopologyViews/deleteSegment    `                 I did like so...Request body of the console on IE shows -"No data to view" and No alerts were prompted.

Comment: Hi finally found the error.My IE 10 not working properly.Sorry for your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

your script works fine.

Check the next:

1. Your jquery file is included or link is valid.
2. Be sure to use  script `type="text/javascript"` and NOT script `type="application/javascript"` , on every script tag.
3. first load jquery , then your ajax script.

forgot to mention , declare segment before your ajax.  `var segment="some value"`;

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I have done all the things that you mentioned.This works fine on Firefox,Chrome and IE 9.But not on IE 10.